# How do you set the repositories path in gitosis?

Tags: ssh, git

I'm setting up gitosis on a NearlyFreeSpeech.net account with a ["virtual" Python](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#creating-a-virtual-python). I tried to clone the gitosis-admin.git repository. The command below doesn't work.

```
$ git clone  tlevine_thomaslevinecom@ssh.phx.nearlyfreespeech.net:gitosis-admin.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tlevine/bar/a/gitosis-admin/.git/
tlevine_thomaslevinecom@ssh.phx.nearlyfreespeech.net's password: 
fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The command below does.

```
$ git clone  tlevine_thomaslevinecom@ssh.phx.nearlyfreespeech.net:~/repositories/gitosis-admin.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tlevine/bar/a/gitosis-admin/.git/
tlevine_thomaslevinecom@ssh.phx.nearlyfreespeech.net's password: 
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (8/8), 1.06 KiB, done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0)
```

It would be convenient if I didn't have to type "~/repositories/". I tried editing gitosis.conf.

```
[gitosis]
repositories = ~/repositories/

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = tlevine@tlevine-laptop
```

I added the "repositories" line above. It didn't change the results of either of the git-clone commands. Is there a way I can make first command work?

Comment: I actually think now that gitosis wasn't working at all, perhaps because I didn't configure gitosis properly for the bizarre environment. This would explain why I was having the problem I was and why I had to type in my password.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an absolute path in the conf file instead of the ~.

You may also want to try [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). It's more actively maintained and has a wider feature set.

You can also create your own "programs" in bash called aliases. [This article](http://lifehacker.com/5743814/become-a-command-line-ninja-with-these-time+saving-shortcuts) has a how-to towards the bottom. It's a huge time saver.